# iOS - Parse Push Notifications, some Users wont receive push

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have currently set up Parse Push notifications. I am running a beta with a few of my friends, and it seems that I am the only iPhone is that able to receive push notifications. The badge increments, sound and message, all is there for me.

On the Push tab in Parse the "Pushes Sent" column shows "1" for pushes sent to my iPhone, and "0" for Pushes sent from my iPhone.

We are all using the same build. And all have set notifications on in settings.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Your friends, are added in your development certificate (I mean, their devices)?

Comment: I guess not. How do I add them. If i did external testers would that allow push notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as your app is in Development Mode you should register your friends UDID'S in the [Apple Developer Portal Devices Section](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2F%2Faccount%2Fios%2Fdevice%2Fdevicelist.action).

Once you have done that, you should generate a new Development certificate now including your friends devices so they are also signed to receive the same services as you.

Check out one more time the [Parse Certificates Tutorial](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) and make sure you are signing your app with the correct certificate and uploading the correct one to Parse Push Settings.

When installing the app please also make sure the certificate is the updated one and you are signing with it.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: I just decided to start external testing. This will allow push notifications to work correct?

Comment: Thats correct, you have to generate a distribution certificate with all the distribution APNS steps in order to put your push notifications to work.